# Connecting a 6pin mini-DIN RF power sensor to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: rf, adc, raspberry-pi

I have a Wavenode UHF-1 RF power sensor that needs to be connected to a computer to show digital readings to support my ground segment equipment.

The RF power sensor has a 6pin mini-DIN analog output port. This needs to be converted to digital and connected to a Raspberry Pi. Before ADC conversion, this sensor is stated to follow a circuit as mentioned by the manufacturer as shown below.

I am looking for suggestions regarding the connections and how I can connect this type of sensor to the Raspberry Pi. (The Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't have a  mini-DIN interface.)

[Wavenode UHF-1 RF sensor](https://wavenodedevelop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Technote-101-Mindin-interface.pdf)

[image]

Comment: what's there to suggest? ... you either find a matching connector, or you replace the existing connector with some other connector

Comment: The pi doesn't have an ADC module, either, so you have a bit of design work to do.  You can't just ask for a connection from A to B when you need to put a whole module in between A and B